# Php active deactive with checkbox

Tags: php, arrays, list

I have form including multiple checkbox. Each checkbox for a system feature.

I want list all system feature as checkbox and give 'checked' attribute be active features. So no problems here. But i want if unchecked active feature, this feature make deactive. And if checked deactive feature, this make active.

But which i don't know how to distinguish the previously selected.

I write as a code;

```
    function generate_menu($parent)
{
    $has_childs = false;
    global $activeModule;
    global $actives;
    global $menu_array;
    foreach($menu_array as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($value['cat'] == $parent) 
        {              
            if ($has_childs === false)
            {                        
                $has_childs = true;
                echo '<ul id="categories" style="list-style:none;">';
            } 
            echo '<li><label><input name="module[]" type="checkbox" '.(($value['check'])?'checked':'').' value="'.$value['id'].'"> ' . $value['modulename'] .'</label>';
            generate_menu($key); 
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    if ($has_childs === true) 
        echo '</ul>';

}
```

**The result of this code**

[image]

**To save the currently selected ;**

```
$success = Array();
            foreach($_POST['module'] as $key=>$val)
            {
                $db->where('lisansID', $_POST['licence']);
                $db->where('modulID', $val);
                if(!$db->has('moduleactivation'))
                {
                    if($db->insert('moduleactivation', Array(
                        'lisansID'      =>  $_POST['licence'],
                        'modulID'       =>  $val,
                        'start'         =>  $_POST['start'],
                        'end'           =>  $_POST['end'],
                        'activatedate'  =>  $_POST['adate']
                    )))
                    {
                        $result['relocation']   =   'asd.php';
                        $success[]              =    $val;
                        $result['msg']          =   'Success Process, add module of licence.';
                        $result['code']         =   '200';

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $error = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    $unique     = true;
                    $uniqueR[]  = $val;
                }
```

How to detect unchecked checkbox and if has in database make delete?

Answer (score 0):

As you've found out, PHP will only receive values in `$_POST` for checked boxes. To check for an 'unchecked' box, you will have to loop through a list of known check boxes and check for that variable name in `$_POST` Luckily, you already have this list in `$menu_array`:

```
foreach ($menu_array as $varName => $varValue)
{
    if (array_key_present($varName,$_POST)===TRUE) // Has it been selected?
    {
        echo "{$varName} is checked".PHP_EOL;
        /*
         * Do your activation bit here
         */
    } else
    {
        echo "{$varName} is unchecked".PHP_EOL
        /*
         * Do your deactivation bit here
         */
    }
}
```